# Iterating through a nested hash map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Am trying to loop through nested values in a HashMap. 
The values looks like this:

```
{names={SomeName={age=1,otherInfo={a=1,b=2,c=3}},SomeOtherName={age=1,otherInfo={a=1,b=2,c=3}}}
```

I want to be able to do something similar to the code that is commented.
The line "HashMap names = (HashMap) pairs;" gives me this error:

```
LinkedHashMap$LinkedValueIterator.next() line: 739 [local variables unavailable]
```

I want to end up being able to print out something like:

"SomeName is 1 years old and info a is 1 and c is 3"

This is my code so far:

```
HashMap map = (HashMap) yaml.load(input);
Iterator i = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    if (pairs.getKey().toString().equals("names")){
        HashMap names = (HashMap) pairs;
          // Iterator namesI = names.entrySet().iterator();
          // while(namesI.hasNext()){
              // Map.Entry p = (Map.Entry)namesI.next();
          //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pairs variable is a Map Entry variable, but the value if it is probably a HashMap according to the description of your problem. Try `HashMap names = (HashMap) pairs.getValue();`.